# How to send "Security : low" to DVWA as cookie parameter using Jsoup?

Tags: java, session, cookies, jsoup, sql-injection

I am trying to send a request using jsoup with manually inserted cookies for the purpose of detecting SQL injection vulnerability.
The problem seams to be that only one of the cookies works and i don't understand why.
I first authenticate myself manually and get the cookies. Example:

```
PHPSESSID : b74302c3c6af62d23047a450a40cbf5a
security : high
```

After i got the cookies i send my request (which whould look like this from the browser http://localhost:8090/dvwa/vulnerabilities/sqli/?id='&Submit=Submit#) using the same PHPSESSID but with **Security : *low***. The purpose is to force a "You have an error in your SQL syntax" response that signals SQL Injection vulnerability. The problem is that the PHPSESSID is received good (since I retrieve the dvwa/vulnerabilities/sqli page and not Login page thus it recognizes the PHPSESSID  as valid after authentication) but the "security : low" seems not to work. I can't find the problem.

The jsoup code for an initial connection so that i can parse the forms on the page looks like this. I supply the cookies manually.

```
Connection  connection = Jsoup.connect(urlDTO.getUrl())
                        .userAgent(StringConstants.USER_AGENT)
                        .cookies(cookies)//Map<String,String>
                        .referrer(StringConstants.REFERRER);

Document htmlDocument = connection.get();
```

For sending the form i use this code:

```
Connection  connection = Jsoup.connect(formDTO.getUrl())
                        .userAgent(StringConstants.USER_AGENT)
                        .cookies(cookies)
                        .data(listToMap(formDTO.getInputList()))// id = ' , Submit = Submit
                        .method(getMethod(formDTO.getMethod()))
                        .referrer(StringConstants.REFERRER);

Connection.Response res = connection.execute();
Document doc = res.parse();
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much debugging I fund out the origin of the problem and the odd behavior. There was no problem with the cookies/headers/url, the problem was at the  `.method()`. The default value of `.method()` is `Method.GET`. But since i was sending dynamic requests i had to construct this dynamically also. For this purpose i was parsing the forms to get the method and then adding the type needed in the connection construction.

```
if (method.equals("post")) {
            return Method.POST;
        }
if (method.equals("get")) {
            return Method.GET;
        }
return Method.POST;
```

This worked until now and surprisingly when sending the wrong method it still sent a response almost valid, so i overlooked it.

Here is the fix.

```
if (method.toLowerCase().equals("post")) {
            return Method.POST;
        }
if (method.toLowerCase().equals("get")) {
            return Method.GET;
        }
return Method.GET;
```

It was my mistake and not relay a Jsoup problem but since I overlooked it others might too so here is a reminder.